# Regex with double quotes in PIG

Tags: java, regex, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm writing a pig script to process an access log from a sophos proxy.

Each line is like:

> 2015:01:13-00:00:01 AR-BADC-FAST-01 httpproxy[27983]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="GET" srcip="10.20.7.210" dstip="10.24.2.7" user="" ad_domain="" statuscode="302" cached="0" profile="REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Web Filter Profile)" filteraction="REF_DefaultHTTPCFFAction (Default content filter action)" size="0" request="0x9ac68d0" url="http://www.google.com" exceptions="av,auth,content,url,ssl,certcheck,certdate,mime,cache,fileextension" error="" authtime="0" dnstime="1" cattime="0" avscantime="0" fullreqtime="239428" device="0" auth="0"

So I managed to do it in Java with MapReduce, using the following regex: `\"([^\"]*)\"` to get the values between the quotes and then process it. Now I want to do the same with pig, but I'm not able to apply the regex to the each of the lines.

I'm doing:

```
input = load './http.log' as (line : chararray);
splt = foreach input generate FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(\\"([^\\"]*)\\")'));
dump splt;
```

And the result of the dump is: ().

There is something that I'm missing with the use of REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL or I have to escape some characters of the regex in a different way?

Thanks!

Comment: Double quotes are nothing special in regexes, no need to quote them; you have to do so in Java only because in string literals, you have to quote them. But since it appears that PIG doesn't need that, just remove the backslashes.

Comment: @fge I need the regex in this way: `\"([^\"]*)\"` in order to get all the values between the quotes, like this: https://www.regex101.com/r/yF8xN8/1. But if I don't scape the \, I get: `Unexpected character '"'` when executing the pig script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to extract the values with a different approach, because I just wanted some of the fields of the line.

In order to get the values I'm doing:

```
splt = FOREACH A GENERATE
    FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT(line,'.*url="([^"]*)".*',1)) AS url,
    FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT(line,'.*fullreqtime="([^"]*)".*',1)) AS duration,
    FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT(line,'.*size="([^"]*)".*',1)) AS bytes;
```

And then I can continue with the rest of the script